# Force HTST cache reset from webserver

Tags: node.js, caching, nginx, hsts

I'm using `nginx` as reverse proxy and `nodejs` for the application. I want to know is there any solutions to force `HSTS` or HTTPS Strict Transport Security from webserver?

I don't want to ask users to reset their browser cache because its really technical and they don't know how to address this issue.

Comment: I can't understand how title is relevant to post? Have you missed something?

Comment: @AlexeyTen nope, I wrote all I need. I need a solution to reset HTST cache from webserver (e.g. nginx)

Comment: I guess, you need `max-age=0` http://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc6797#section-6.1.1

Comment: @AlexeyTen well, `max-age` resets browser cache but its nothing to do with `HTST` cache.

Comment: Where did you put it?

Comment: @AlexeyTen inside nginx config

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `max-age = 0` to reset cache and force HTST cache reset.

In nginx:

```
server {
   ...
   add_header  Strict-Transport-Security "max-age=0;";
   ...
}
```